# How to delete the last 3 characters from every line in a file?

Tags: python, file, character

Can anyone give me some advice on creating a loop to cut the last 3 characters from every line within a input file?

I have tried

```
iFile = iFile[:-3]
```

and

```
iFile = iFile.replace(':', '')[:-3]
```

but neither seem to work as I'm getting a:

```
TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Can you please provide your full code? What is `iFile` for example? Is it an open file object? A string?

Comment: You need to `read()` the file before you can even start to manipulate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use regular expression string substitution. This helps to prevent `IndexError` if you have lines that are shorter than three characters:

```
import re
with open(fileName, 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        print re.sub('.{0,3}\Z', '', line)
```

Answer (score 2):

First open the file and then 
you will have to loop over the lines as follows

```
myfile = open(fileName)
for j in myfile:
    print j[:-3]
```

That all!

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
iFile = iFile[:-3]
```

with

```
line = line[:-3]
```